# How can I set the localization of my local debugger?

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm using arabic in my app (in various text fields, etc.), but for some reason all my print statements print in arabic. For example if I print `Date.now` I get ٨:٤١:٢٩ +0000.

Nice but not ideal for my use case. How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Going to edit scheme > run > app language

Once I set the app language - this did the trick.